# Usar una segunda base de datos firebase realtime

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Estoy intentando descubrir como puedo añadir otro proyecto de firebase a mi aplicación android, tengo ya uno añadido y estoy utilizándolo pero quisiera utilizar otro.

Comment: [Lee esto](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding). Si aún tienes dudas dinos cuáles son en concreto y lo que has investigado. Saludos.

Comment: Acabo de ver el enlace que me has pasado pero para poder utilizar mas de una base de datos en el mismo proyecto se necesita pasar por caja y no me lo permito porque soy un estudiante. Lo he intentado crear otro proyecto en el firebase con la otra base de datos y utilizar-la en la misma aplicación android.

Comment: Parece que también es posible, [mira aquí un ejemplo del código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37643374/5587982) para poder conectar las dos bases de datos. Aunque tengo curiosidad por saber por qué dos bases de datos, ¿alcanzaste los límites en la primera de ellas?